# Trying to set up homepage with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, hosting, web-hosting

So I recently purchased a domain. I know how to make websites, so I uploaded a website that I made onto that domain. The only problem is is that it sends me to my index and then I have to click on some folders to actually get to see my website on my screen. I know what .htaccess is and does, but I'm not sure how to use it.
What I want is that when I go to www.mydomain.com it should open up my home.php file from the website that I made. This is my file order:
project/PHP/home.php
I'm not sure if I've given enough information, but I hope someone can help me out here.

Comment: Simplest solution would be to just rename the file to index.php, web servers are usually set up to serve files named index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As correctly written by @JimL in the comments above we would recommend that you simply replace `home.php` to `index.php`, since that is the default setting really all http servers are configured to use for the index document.

You can however change that, even if you can only use `.htaccess` style files:

```
DirectoryIndex home.php
```

That said I still would recommend to rename the index file instead. `.htaccess` style files should be avoided whenever possible. They are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow the http server down, often without reason. They are only offered for cases where you really need to do some configuration tweaks but do not have control over the http servers host configuration. That is for example often the case when using a cheap web space provider.

---

Considering the additional information you gave in the comment below you could also try to rewrite all requests to point to the php scripts inside that folder `project/php`. For that you can place such rewriting rules inside a `.htaccess` style file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/project/php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ project/php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

If you also have to handle requests that require different rewriting then obviously you need additional rules.

But as already said in the comments below this is painful, slows the server down and makes things harder to debug.

Comment: I've renamed it to index.php, and I've uploaded the whole "project" map onto my domain, but it still gives me the index of / page, and I still have to click on project>php to "open" my website. I have only purchased my domain today, so maybe that's got something to do with it?

Comment: What do you mean by "have to click on project>php"? What is "project>php" here?

Comment: And no, this has nothing to do with a domain, this is a question of how the http server works / is configured / handles your request.

Comment: "project" is the map that has all my website files inside of it, and php is the next folder that has all my .php files inside, including index.php

Comment: Ah, OK, I understand. That won't work, obviously. An http server has no idea about your folder structure. It does not know that you want a "project" folder to be treated different. Place your structure directly inside the document root folder of your web space. The `index.php` file should also be located there, not buried somewhere inside subfolders. You could try to rewrite all that internally, but that would be quite a pain and offer no advantage in the end...

Answer (score 0):

Put your files in the `public_html` folder, or `/var/www`, you don't need the `.htacces` to do this.

Comment: I put my whole "project" mapfile in public_html, but when I go to my domain it still gives me all the mapfolders, including the "project" mapfile. I still have to click on project/php/home.php for me to actually see my website.

Comment: your home.php needs to be in public_html -> public_html/home.php, after this, you can rename or chante your .htaccess
maybe the problem is to upload all your project, try to upload just the content of the "project/php" folder into the public_html folder